# Looping/iterating based on table names in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, iteration

Currently I have 2 tables in SQL Server: `tab_master` (current month table) and `tab_08_2022` (indicating it refers to Aug data based on the timestamp).

The tables have exactly structures, the only difference being they pertain to different months.

There will be more tables coming in for subsequent months: `tab_08_2022`, `tab_09_2022`, `tab_10_2022` and so on.

I need to count the number of rows for each flag (grouping by the flag column) and showcase them every month. This should also have the data from all the previous month's tables.

For one table the query could be:

```
select count(*), flag_col  
from tab_master
group by flag_col;
```

When the second table comes in the query would be

```
select * 
from 
    (select count(*), flag_col  
     from tab_master 
     group by flag_col) x
inner join 
    (select count(*), flag_col as flag_08_2022 
     from tab_09_2022 
     group by flag_col) y on x.flag = y.flag_08_2022;
```

When the third table comes in the query would be

```
select * 
from 
    (select count(*), flag_col  
     from tab_master 
     group by flag_col) x
inner join 
    (select count(*), flag_col as flag_08_2022 
     from tab_08_2022 
     group by flag) y on x.flag = y.flag_08_2022
inner join 
    (select count(*), flag_col as flag_09_2022 
     from tab_09_2022 
     group by flag_col) z on x.flag_col = z.flag_09_2022;
```

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Better idea: why not normalize your database design instead? Manually partitioning data into tables is a anti-pattern.

Comment: Just don't. Denormalization is the path to the dark side. Combine it all into one table and life becomes simple.

Comment: i have such a system on an embeded server, and rely heavy on stored prcedure, which will first detect which tables exist(or else the query will fail) and use dynamic sql to build my queries, but of course that isn't quick

Comment: Why do you want to make life so difficult for yourself and your fellow programmers ? This denormalization is only getting you into troubles and will shorten your life because of all the stress it will introduce. Take the advice in the comments above and keep it all in one table.

Comment: I would suggest to go with what is mentioned in the comments.
You can try below approach:
1. Combine every months data into single table (e.g.  [master_month_table])
2. Add one column to the [master_month_table] that uniquely identify the records for each month (e.g. [Month_Year] flag)
3. Use that column in group by query (first query) that you have written by joining the [master_month_table] table.

this way you will get the desired output.